Magento 2 : Responsive design for Page builder on mobile and desktop
I am using page builder on Adobe commerce.
Is it possible to build a responsive page with page builder.
What I mean by this is that I wish to place text on a background image. I need the text to be placed in different positions dependent on whether the user is using a mobile or a desktop.

Yes, you will have to change the viewport on the top part of the pagebuilder and make the appropriate changes for that viewport (i.e mobile or desktop). You can also add custom viewports and breakpoints.
You can check the official documentation to check how all these work, follow following link;
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/page-builder/viewports/
If you want to add custom viewports and breakpoints, the documentation for them are also available in the same section.

hey Vivek. Thank you so much for your help.

Happy to help :)
